# Kafka connect standalone issue: disconnecting broker

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I am new and this is my first question. I hope it is not a duplicate, I haven't found an answer to my issue. I followed tutorials mostly (Medium/Youtube). I also tried using offical documentation, but kafka is new to me and there is a lot to sink in.

I am trying to connect to a kafka broker I have no control of and pipe the data into a snowflake table.
I got SSL connection files, a topic and :.

**Setup:**

- ubuntu 20.04
- Java openjdk 1.8.0362
- Kafka 3.2.1
- snowflake-kafka-connector-1.9.1

**What works**

I am able to consume data by running:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config kafka/config/connect-custom.properties --topic <my_topic> --bootstrap-server <server>:<port>
```

I am also able to create my own producer and run the following with standard configuration on localhost

```
kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties kafka/config/connect-snowflake-kafka-connector.properties
```

**What does not work:**

Now I want to get the production data into Snowflake and run the following:

```
kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh kafka/config/connect-**custom**.properties kafka/config/connect-snowflake-kafka-connector.properties
```

Here I get the following Info/Warnings and nothing else happens:

```
[2023-04-11 14:54:06,975] INFO [snowflakesink|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakesink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakesink] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935)
[2023-04-11 14:54:06,975] INFO [snowflakesink|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakesink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakesink] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 32 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 79ms, elapsed time since send: 79ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341)
[2023-04-11 14:54:06,975] WARN [snowflakesink|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakesink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakesink] Bootstrap broker <server>:<port> (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1063)
```

**Files:**

*connect-custom.properties:*

```
bootstrap.servers=<server>:<port>

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore
ssl.truststore.password=***
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=***
ssl.key.password=***
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

I tried other Java and Kafka versions, which resulted in the same Warning messages.
Also tried to include a plugin path. I guess, that there is an issue with the property file.

**Solution:**

Include SSL connection information for the consumer:

```
bootstrap.servers=<server>:<port>

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore
ssl.truststore.password=***
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore
ssl.keystore.password=***
ssl.key.password=***

consumer.security.protocol=SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
consumer.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=***
consumer.ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore
consumer.ssl.keystore.password=***
consumer.ssl.key.password=***

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

Comment: Can you enable logging on the [Kafka connector and JDBC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts#reporting-issues) and provide some information from there?

Comment: The Confluent documentation covers SSL with Connect... Basically, you need to repeat the SSL settings a few times for Connect itself, then actual Kafka consumer client with `consumer.` prefixed properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks! That resolved the issue! Apparently I was looking on the wrong documentation.

How can I mark your comment as correct answer?

Comment: @Sergiu thanks for the tip. Somehow I haven't thought about additional logfiles. I will use them on my next problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, the Kafka documentation itself is sparse.

The Confluent documentation covers SSL with Connect much better... Basically, you need to repeat the SSL settings a few times for Connect itself, then actual Kafka consumer client with `consumer.` (and `admin.`) prefixed properties.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/security.html